# What are the available types for Windows Workflow Foundation 4?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow-foundation-4, sharepoint-workflow

I have a Visual Studio 2013 workflow running inside of SharePoint 2013 (SharePoint Online).  In an Assign activity I want to UrlDecode a string; however, I don't seem to have access to System.Web.HttpUtility, System.Web.HttpServerUtility, or System.Net.WebUtility.

Not only would like to know how to urldecode a string within an Assign activity, I would like to know how to find out what set of namespaces I can use.

Note that SharePoint 2013 (esp. SharePoint Online) does not allow custom activities.

Comment: FWIW—You don't use namespaces; You use types. Types are exported from assemblies loaded into an AppDomain. This gets you a list of the namespaces of the types in the current AppDomain: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes).Select(t => t.Namespace).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n)`. Of course, a list of types or assemblies might be more useful. A type is defined in exactly one assembly. Types in the same namespace can be provided by different assemblies. There is no hard requirement relating names of types, namespaces, assemblies and files.

Comment: Valid point.  I knew when I asked the question it didn't sound right.   I have updated the subject.  Thanks.